# error in xml files in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have three xml files for the spring project as follows

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"   
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc  http://www.springframework.org/schema 
      /jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   http://www.springframework.org/schema 
    /tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema 
    /util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   http://www.springframework.org/schema 
     /mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema 
     /context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


 <context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="basicDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/indi" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />

 </bean>  

</beans>
```

CController-servlet.xml(It is manager level xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  http://www.springframework.org/schema 
      /aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema
      /tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema
   /util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema 
     /context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

  <context:annotation-config/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="project4"/>

 <bean  
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>


 <bean id="urlMapping"   
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>


        </props>
    </property>
</bean>



<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />


<bean name="frm4" class="project4.CController" >
    <property name="userDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
</bean>


<bean name="indexController"  
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

and UUController-servlet.xml(this is a dao level xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  http://www.springframework.org/schema 
    /aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema
     /tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema
   /util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema
    /context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">



<bean id="mySessionFactory"   
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="project4"/>

      <property name="hibernateProperties">
          <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
          </props>
      </property>
  </bean>

<bean id="myUserDAO" class="project4.UserDAOImpl1">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

i have two xml files one for manager call and another for dao call...i know ref link from one xml points to the bean in another xml.I thought they will automatically link but i am getting the following error

```
 Error creating bean with name  
'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping#0'
 defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/CController-servlet.xml]: Initialization
 of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
 'frm4' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/CController-servlet.xml]: Cannot 
  resolve reference to bean 'myUserDAO' while setting bean property 'userDAO'; nested 
  exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
    bean     named 'myUserDAO' is defined



Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'frm4' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/CController-
servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myUserDAO' while setting bean property
  'userDAO'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 
'myUserDAO' is defined
```

UserDAOImpl1 is my hibernate template class and CCController is my spring controller class

CCController.java

```
package project4;
import project4.UserDAO1;
import project4.User1;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("frm4.do")

public class CController{

   private UserDAO1 userDAO;

    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO1 userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView add( @ModelAttribute("add") User1 user,HttpServletRequest 
            request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        userDAO.saveUser(user);
        System.out.println("hai");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ModelAndView delete(@ModelAttribute("delete") User1 user,HttpServletRequest
           request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
           userDAO.deleteUser(user);
           return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }

    @RequestMapping(params = "find", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ModelAndView find(@ModelAttribute("find") User1 user,HttpServletRequest 
                  request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  
                     userDAO.findUser(user);
                      return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }


    @RequestMapping(params = "update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("update") User1 user,HttpServletRequest
               request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  
                     userDAO.updateUser(user);
                      return new ModelAndView("redirect:list.htm");
    }

    public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


    ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
    modelMap.addAttribute("userList", userDAO.listUser());
    modelMap.addAttribute("user", new User1());
    return new ModelAndView("userForm", modelMap);
  }
  }
```

can someone help plz

EDIT:

the web.xml is as follows

```
 <context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value> /WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>     
 </context-param>  

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener- 
     class>
 </listener>


 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: can you share the web.xml also

Comment: added it along with the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frm4` bean has a property which has reference to `userDAO`, which is declared in other xml file. So make sure all the xml files are loaded in application context. To do this you need to add all the xml files in web.xml.

Try this :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/UUController-servlet.xml,
    /WEB-INF/application-context.xml,
    /WEB-INF/CController-servlet.xml
    </param-value>     
</context-param>
```

**EDIT :** 
If this is not working for you. Try adding other files in application-context.xml file. Use bean import tag.

```
<beans:import resource="/WEB-INF/UUController-servlet.xml"/>
<beans:import resource="/WEB-INF/CController-servlet.xml"/>
```

And load only application-context file at startup.

**EDIT :**

The reason behind the error 'Cannot map handler' is that you are scanning components at application startup and also having the same bean declared in application context.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="project4"/>
```

&

```
<bean name="frm4" class="project4.CController" >
    <property name="userDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
</bean>
```

Remove bean declaration from xml file since you already have scanned that particular component. And autowire `myUserDAO` bean in you controller class.

```
@Autowire
@Qualifier("myUserDAO")
private UserDAOImpl1 myUserDAO;
```

Comment: Confirm if xml file paths are correct. Check if they are under WEB-INF only and not in nested folder under WEB-INF.

Comment: hi now its showing the error as "Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/UUser-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'myDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; No bean named 'myDataSource' is defined

Comment: Your datasource bean name is basicDataSource and not myDataSource. Change bean tag to <property name="dataSource" ref="basicDataSource" />

Comment: thanks a bunch tht error is cleared,but now i am getting a different error "Cannot map handler 'frm4' to URL path [/c]: There is already handler of type [class project4.CController]  mapped."                 If i am not bothering u much can u help me with this...

Comment: @user1847395 Did it help you get rid of issues?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `UUController-servlet` file is not loaded by the application context. Since it is a db level context add this to `contextConfigLocation` as shown below. Also I would recommend renaming it to `dao-context.xml`

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/UUController-servlet.xml
    </param-value>     
 </context-param>
```

Comment: Arun - I guess file entries should be comma separated.